# how to delete particulate product from realm database?

Tags: realm

How to find my realm file?

I'm create first time  realm database in my application . There is some problem for delete particular product from list. I make separate class  for adapter and main class

this is my adapter

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
    Card_item cc = card_items.get(position);      
}
```

Comment: in AS 3.0, you can use "Device File Explorer" in the bottom right corner in AS

Comment: `Realm.getPath()`